# html php identifying the form posting data

Tags: php, html

I have a php page which has multiple form tags. each form is dealing with a specific tab. It is simply a search but each tab provides a search of either date, number, or name.

each form tag has a different name....how can I know which form was submitted in the result page to customize the database search accordingly?

is it something with $_POST or $_REQUEST ?

```
    <form name="invoice" action="result.php" method="POST"><br><br>
    <form name="customer" action="result.php" method="POST"><br><br>
    <form name="customer" action="result.php" method="POST"><br><br>
```

each of the above contains a table with input box and submit button.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for one, in each submit button add a name and value, like so:

```
<form>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="search_invoice" />
   ... 
</form>

<form>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="search_customer" />
   ...
</form>
```

then in your php

```
switch($_POST['action']) {
   case 'search_invoice':
      // ur code
      break;

   case 'search_customer': default:
      // ur code
      break;
}
```

Be aware though, older versions of firefox doesn't properly submits the key => value pair of input type submit.

Another solution I usually use is to put an `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="your_customAction" />`

Comment: Thanks mate...I will go ahead with the hidden field like suggested earlier but good to have alternatives

Comment: Internet Explorer does not send the submit button as a POST variable if the user pressed the enter key to submit the form.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest adding a hidden input field for each form specifying the form name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="invoice" />
```

Then you can get this with the $_POST['formname'] variable.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to store a different hidden input in each form, and then check for that hidden input on the server side to figure out which form it is.

```
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="invoice" />
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="customer" />
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="customer2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Search should be performed using GET method, not POST
2. no `name` attribute being sent to the server.
3. If each tab provides a search of either date, number, or name - why don't you have the names of the search fields accordingly: `"date"` for the date search etc.?

Answer (score -2):

You should have different name of submit button in all the forms.

EDIT:-

If you have only one element in each form your best bet is to use @Petter's solution because IE having bug with the single text element- That it is if you submit the form using the enter key the submit button will not set in `$_POST`.

But if you have more than one element in the forms you can consider the choosing different name for submit buttons.

Comment: the submit button isn't always posted -- if you submit the form via enter key in some cases

Comment: That is a good solution for determining which submit button was used to submit a form, but when there are multiple forms, a hidden input is safer (as it cannot be bypassed by using the right browser and pressing enter in a text field).

Comment: @dldnh: Give a try it by yourself

Comment: @Quentin: You can not By Pass by pressing enter in a text field with this as well.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh — Yes, you can. I just built a test case. In IE, the submit button's value was only submitted if I explicitly clicked the button. If I just typed in the text field and pressed enter, only the value of the text field was submitted.

Comment: @Quentin: True, Tested. IE is really bad

Comment: The specification was ambiguous. IE is not at fault.

Comment: @Quentin: I tested it again. Some time it works with some input element and another time it does not. don't know what's going on with IE

Comment: @Quentin: If you test this code in IE it works perfectly fine. http://codepad.org/nqDs4hK6 and if you comment out one input text element from each form it does not.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh: If you give it a try by yourself with IE8 (8.0.6001.18702) you will see that the button is not posted if you submit the form using the Enter key.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh, would you mind explaining whether your updated answer would provide a solution for IE?

Comment: @dldnh: Updated answer contains much more than an answer. It also speaking about the IE bug and solution towards.