# Pressing enter with in text box, submit button set, unset issue with IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, submit, enter

I have a form in a PHP script and one text field. However when I press the enter key in a text field, the submit button does not set in the `$_POST` array.

But when I have two text fields in the form the submit button is set in the `$_POST` array.

This is happening in IE. Can anyone explain the reason behind this?

Below is the code I am testing with

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="frmdata">
<input type="text" name="abc1" id="abc1" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
<input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit1" id="submit1" />
</form>
```

If I remove one of the text box and submit the form by pressing enter key while entering text in the text box, IE does not set `Submit` button in `$_POST` array.

This does not set the Submit Button:-

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="frmdata">
<input type="text" name="abc1" id="abc1" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit1" id="submit1" />
</form>
```

I actually got this while answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717835/html-php-identifying-the-form-posting-data/9717864#comment12355163_9717864) question.

Comment: Does it matter *which* input you remove?

Comment: @Chris: You can test it by removing any text element.It does not set `submit` when there is only one text input element and a submit button in the form.

Comment: I asked if it matters **which** of the two text inputs you remove, because I am unable to reproduce this. Can you edit your post to include the "broken" version as well?

Comment: Check this out: http://style-vs-substance.com/development/form-submit-by-enter-key-and-internet-explorer/

Comment: According to the link from @Yaniro, it looks like that's a known IE bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Yaniro. It is a [IE bug](http://style-vs-substance.com/development/form-submit-by-enter-key-and-internet-explorer/).

IE having bug with the single text element- That it is if you submit the form using the enter key the `Submit` button will not set in `$_POST`.

You must have at least 2 form element if you want `submit button` to set in `$_POST` when form submitted by pressing Enter key in IE.